# c++ Difficulty initializing a struct using 'auto'

Tags: c++

Having difficulty initializing a `struct` consisting of a tree node and a `bool` using `auto [aaa, aaa]` syntax:

> Identifier 'node' is undefined

I've tried using the `struct` type (`NodeAndState`) as well as `decltype` instead of `auto`, but nothing seems to work.

The code is exactly as in "Elements of Programming Interviews".

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode
{
    T data;
    unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>> left, right;

    explicit BinaryTreeNode(const T& data) : data(data) {}
    
    BinaryTreeNode(T data, unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>>&& left,
        unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>>&& right) : data(data), left(move(left)),
        right(move(right)) {}
};


vector<int> InorderTraversal(const unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>>& tree) {
  vector<int> result;

  struct NodeAndState {
    const BinaryTreeNode<int>* node;
    bool left_subtree_traversed;
  };
  stack<NodeAndState> in_process(
      {{tree.get(), false}});
  while (!empty(in_process)) {
    // The problem is here
    auto [node, left_subtree_traversed] = in_process.top();
    in_process.pop();
    if (node) {
      if (left_subtree_traversed) {
        result.emplace_back(node->data);
      } else {
        in_process.push({node->right.get(), false});
        in_process.push({node, true});
        in_process.push({node->left.get(), false});
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C++17 mode or higher when compiling?

Comment: GCC compiles it as long as you enable C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/fPvWxh1hn

Comment: [Compiles fine here when specifying C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6b64f5a5d17e3e4).  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I just checked in Properties it is c++14

Comment: Okay, thanks guys it is compiling in 17

Comment: You'll need to use at least C++17, as that was when this feature was added to the language.